# getimagesize returns bool(false)

Tags: php, wordpress

I have created a WordPress plugin where you can choose a file with the media uploader:

```
    <input type="text" id="clb_setting_logo" name="clb_plugin_options[clb_setting_logo]" value="<?php echo esc_url( $options['clb_setting_logo'] ); ?>" />
    <input id="upload_logo_button" type="button" class="button" value="<?php _e( 'Choose Image', 'clb' ); ?>" />
    <span class="description"><?php _e('Choose an image for the button.', 'clb' ); ?></span>
```

When I choose an image from the media uploader the path is taken into the field #clb_setting_logo which can be seen above.

Within another function I try to access the dimensions as this:

```
if (!empty($options['clb_setting_logo'])) {
    $imagesize = getimagesize($options['clb_setting_logo']);
```

It runs perfectly on two servers, on another server getimagesize returns bool(false), but why? First I thought this happens because the normal file path is taken - so something like this: "http://exmaple.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/02/test.png" - but this works on other installations.

Does anybody know something? Thanks!

Comment: For `getimagesize('http://exmaple.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/02/test.png');` to work the server must have the PHP ini setting `allow_url_fopen` enabled otherwise it can only read over the filesystem - is that enabled on 2 of the servers but not the other?

Comment: I do not know exactly, but I habe solved it now. I use wp_get_attachement_image_src - thats easier and will work on all servers.